# Limit Loop to One Category

Tags: categories, loop, limit

I am trying to limit my loop to one category. This is the loop:

```
<?php
$counter = 1; //start counter

$grids = 3; //Grids per row

global $query_string; //Need this to make pagination work


/*Setting up our custom query (In here we are setting it to show 12 posts per page and eliminate all sticky posts) */
query_posts($query_string . '&caller_get_posts=1&posts_per_page=9&category=5');



if(have_posts()) :  while(have_posts()) :  the_post(); 
?>
<?php
//Show the left hand side column
if($counter == 1) :
?>
            <div class="four columns">
                <div class="postimage">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb'); ?></a>
                </div>
                <h3 style="text-align:center;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </div>
<?php
//Show the middle column
elseif($counter == $grids) :
?>
<div class="four columns">
                <div class="postimage">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb'); ?></a>
                </div>
                <h3 style="text-align:center;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </div>
<?php
//Show the right hand side column
elseif($counter == $grids) :
?>
<div class="four columns">
                <div class="postimage">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb'); ?></a>
                </div>
                <h3 style="text-align:center;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </div>          

<div class="clear"></div>
<?php
endif;
?>

<?php
endwhile;
//Pagination can go here if you want it.
endif;
?>
```

This is the page temp.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Web Design
*/
 get_header(); ?>
<hr>

    <div  id="content" class="twelve columns">

        <?php get_template_part('loop', 'web'); ?>

    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It is not working. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `category` argument for `query_posts`, a category ID should be passed via `cat`.

**However**, if this is an additional query, please use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) rather than `query_posts`. If this is the main query, please see [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the main query parameters.

For more info please see [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts).